# Frame to Page Navigation

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

am trying to goto a page from main window by using I have put 4 rectangle around window for framing of main window .

But when I Navigate to page my bottom rectangle is getting shifted(as shown in picture. Its completely ok in main window.[image]

my .xaml file for mainWindow is

```
<Window x:Class="Demo1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

Title="WPF Demo" Height="652" Width="924"  WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  Loaded="Window_Loaded"
 >


<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15">

     <DockPanel Width="899">
            <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
          <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightBlue" CornerRadius="13" BorderThickness="1" Height="462" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="732" Margin="90,80,15,15">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="10" Direction="330" Opacity="0.6"></DropShadowEffect>
                </Border.Effect>
                <DockPanel AllowDrop="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="700" MinHeight="400" Background="LightBlue"  Height="440" Width="700">
                <!--change here-->
                <Button Content="Button" Height="40" Name="button1" Width="89" Click="button1_Click" />
            </DockPanel>

            </Border>


            <!--Bottom polygon-->
            <DockPanel Height="74" Width="888" Margin="-846,520,10,-10">
                    <Polygon   Name="polygon11" Points="0,60,80,0,810,0,875,60" Fill="LightCyan" Height="58" Width="890"  Canvas.Left="-9" Canvas.Top="12" />
            </DockPanel>
        <!--left side polygon-->

            <Canvas Height="557" Name="canvas5" Width="72" Margin="-1030,0,700,0"  >
                <Polygon    Points="0,-10,60,45,60,500,0,545" Fill="LightCyan" Height="582" Width="67"  Canvas.Top="1" Canvas.Left="18" />
            </Canvas>

            <!--Top polygon-->

            <Canvas Height="55" Name="canvas7" Width="857" Margin="-890,-555,0,0" >
                <Polygon   Points="0,0,65,55,800,55,849,0" Fill="LightCyan" Height="59" Width="870"   Canvas.Top="13" Canvas.Left="8"  />
            </Canvas>

            <!--Right side polygon-->

    <Canvas Height="545" Name="canvas6" Width="72" Margin="-80,40,0,80">
        <Polygon Points="0,60,55,0,55,565,0,515" Fill="LightCyan" Height="583" Width="60" Canvas.Top="-14" Canvas.Left="12" />
    </Canvas>
</DockPanel>

       <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="15" Direction="330" Opacity="0.5"></DropShadowEffect>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
```

xaml.cs file is

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _mainFrame.Navigate(new message_box.Page1());
        }
```

Page1 has  this code

```
<Page x:Class="message_box.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="652" d:DesignWidth="924" 
Title="Page1">

<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="15">

    <DockPanel Width="899">
        <Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="LightBlue" CornerRadius="13" BorderThickness="1" Height="462" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="732" Margin="90,80,15,15">
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="10" Direction="330" Opacity="0.6"></DropShadowEffect>
            </Border.Effect>
            <DockPanel AllowDrop="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="700" MinHeight="400" Background="LightBlue"  Height="440" Width="700">

            </DockPanel>

        </Border>

    </DockPanel>

    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="15" Direction="330" Opacity="0.5"></DropShadowEffect>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
</Page>
```

Comment: I don't know if it is related, but as a general rule you should have DockPanel.Dock set on all the items inside your DockPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place your items in a Grid instead. I updated what you should try, but you will have to update your polygons

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>

    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="3">
        <Polygon Points="0,60,80,0,810,0,875,60" Fill="LightCyan"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Polygon Points="0,-10,60,45,60,500,0,545" Fill="LightCyan" />
    </Grid>

    <Canvas Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="0">
        <Polygon Points="0,0,65,55,800,55,849,0" Fill="LightCyan" />
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <Polygon Points="0,60,55,0,55,565,0,515" Fill="LightCyan"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```